# How can I connect 2 different docker containers on 2 ec2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a usecase where I want to run one container on one ec2 and I have 2 such containers. I want container one from ec2 1 to access container 2 on ec2 2. How can I bind the 2 containers on different machines with the same network?

Answer (score 0):

(I assume the two instances are in the same VPC. If not, the answer will be more complicated.)

You need to know the IPs of the two EC2 instances to reference them from each other. You can give them static IPs, or you can use Route 53 and an Infrastructure as Code tool (e.g. CloudFormation or Terraform) to bind the assigned IP to an internal DNS name (e.g. `container-one.internal`).

Then, when you want to call one container from the other, just send an HTTP request and handle it on the receiving side.

Comment: Yes they are in the same VPC but I dont want to connect them using HTTP. I want them to be in the same network as in if I use docker-compose with 2 services, svc1 and svc2. If they 2 are binded by the same network, I can call svc2 directly from svc1 by using the name `svc1` instead of sending an HTTP request.

Comment: What you’re describing and what I’m describing are equivalent. Within a Docker compose project on a single compose instance, compose creates a default network. That’s what you’re using when you call to `svc2`, compose is handling the DNS for you. Because you have two EC2 instances with two different compose projects, you can’t route between the containers using compose. But this isn’t a problem, you will simply use the VPC network instead. It doesn’t have to be an HTTP request, you can use whatever protocol you want.

Comment: So if I have 2 ec2 with each one having an static ip of its own in the same VPC, how would I actually call svc from one ec2 to another?

Comment: Anywhere you would have used the DNS name `svc2`, you would instead use the static IP e.g. `10.0.0.1`. Make sure to specify a port for the service in your compose file, and send the request to that port from the other EC2 instance.